# bsmselect to preselect items during page load and cannot control order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web2py

I am using bsmselect (https://github.com/vicb/bsmSelect) and have the following javascript in-place to preselect items when a page loads. I'm using web2py and {{=fill_messages_saved}} returns an array [4, 144, 142, 143], which all correspond to values of the options I'd like to select. Unfortunately, the order is always displayed in the order generated in my portion of the html. Is there a way to load each item according to the array of values {{=fill_messages_saved}} as preselected options when a page loads? I can watch each item load individually with the alert() below, but they don't load top down.. they retain the order designated in the html. When I manually select the options, they show up correctly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(function($) {
  $("#fill_messages").bsmSelect({
    animate: true,
    highlight: true,
    plugins: [$.bsmSelect.plugins.sortable(), $.bsmSelect.plugins.compatibility()]
  });
});
$(window).load(function(){
  $.each({{=fill_messages_saved}}.toString().split(","), function(i,e){
    alert()
    $("#fill_messages option[value='" + e + "']").prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a repro case without the server side info and html. I'm hoping to have it pre-populate the list with "Chicken", "Sheep,", "Cow", and "Pig" in that order [4,3,2,1], but it shows up "Pig", "Cow", "Sheep", "Chicken" [1,2,3,4].

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(function($) {
   $("#fill_messages").bsmSelect({
        animate: true,
        highlight: true,
        plugins: [$.bsmSelect.plugins.sortable(), $.bsmSelect.plugins.compatibility()]
      });
});
$(window).load(function(){
$.each([4,3,2,1].toString().split(","), function(i,e){
        alert()
        $("#fill_messages option[value='" + e + "']").prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
    });
});

<select name="fill_messages" id="fill_messages" multiple="multiple" title="Select a fill message">
  <option value=1>"Pig"</option>
  <option value=2>"Cow"</option>
  <option value=3>"Sheep"</option>
  <option value=4>"Chicken"</option>
</select>
```